# Are there plans to upgrade DXA to MVC 6?

Tags: dxa

Has anyone tried a DXA upgrade to MVC 6 in .net yet?

Are there any plans to move DXA to MVC 6 in the near future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We do have MVC 6 (or actually ASP.NET MVC Core 1.0) on our roadmap, but at this point we haven't really done anything with it.

I don't know all the technical details, but I understood MVC 6 (or ASP.NET MVC Core 1.0 as they now call it) will no longer support subcontrollers (which are currently being used in DXA) and we should adapt to View Components instead. So that will most likely be the first issue you run into when you will try it.

Because of the amount of work coming from this change, we currently don't have a specific version selected for this. I'm working on making our roadmap a bit more visible for everybody, that way you will have an idea when certain features will come, but for now, all I can say is, we have it on the radar, not sure when you will see it yet.